# Solving non-homegene linear system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, systems-of-equations

$$x'=-y+z-e{-t}$$
$$y'=3x+y-3z$$
$$z'=2x-y-z-2e^{-t}$$

First we have to find the homegene part of the system.
We find the fundamental system of solutions:
$$(e^{t},e^{-2t},te^{t})$$
from the eigenvector we have that 
$$u=(0,1,1)$$
which are the values of the constants (c2,c5,c8) of the system
$$x=C1e^{t}+C2te^{-2t}+C3te^{t}$$
$$x=C4e^{t}+C5te^{-2t}+C6te^{t}$$
$$x=C7e^{t}+C8te^{-2t}+C9te^{t}$$
so I replace these equations in the original system, solve it and I find that:
$$C1=C7;C2=0;C3=-C4=C9;C5=C8;C6=0$$
And so the solution of the homegene part of this equation is :
$$x0=c1e^t+C3te^{-t}$$
$$y0=-C3e^t+C5e^{-2t}$$
$$z=c1e^t+C5e^{-2t}+C3te^{-t}$$

**But that is not right what am I doing wrong?**

After that I have to find the non-homegene part of this system
we have that m=0;alpha=-1;beta=0;s=0
That means that the solution is:
$$x=ae^{-t}$$
$$y=be^{-t}$$
$$z=ce^{-t}$$
and then we replace in the original system and we have:
$$-a+b-c+1=0$$
$$-b-3a-b+3=0$$
$$-2a+b+2=0$$
$$=>a=1;b=c=0$$
and we find that the non homegene part is equal to:
$$x1=1e^{-t}$$
$$x2=0e^{-t}$$
$$x3=0e^{-t}$$

**But that is also not correct according to wolfram, what am I doing wrong here ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the homogeneous part, the matrix has two eigenvalues, one is $-2$, with the eigenvector you found. The other is $1$, which you did not mention at all. You should find the eigenvector $k_1$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda=1$, and another generalized eigenvector $k_2$, since $\lambda=1$ has multiplicity $2$. The solution of the homogeneous part should be
$$\vec{x}=c_1\vec{u}e^{-2t}+c_2(\vec{k}_1te^t+\vec{k}_2e^t).$$

Your set up for the nonhomogeneous part is correct. The matrix is also correct. The solution is not. You can just double check that.

Comment: when I do the eigenvalue thing for lamba = 1, we have that the w1=w3;w2=0 so w=(1,0,1)=k1, k2 should be = (2,0,2) and solution is still wrong I double checked the nonhomogene system, everything is all right

Comment: @Harton: $k_2$ cannot be a multiple of $k_1$. You have to solve $(A-\lambda I)k_2=k_1$. For the nonhomogeneous system, I just double checked my system, the second equation should be $-3a-2b+3c=0$.

Comment: -3a-2b+3x=0=-b-3a-b+3x; k2=k1/(a-lambda*I) which can not be done

Comment: @Harton: The first one, you missed $c$ in your equation $-b-3a-b+3=0$. If there is a $c$, the solution $(1,0,0)$ is not right. For the second one, I wonder how you got the eigenvector $u$. To solve $(A-\lambda I)k_2=k_1$ is similar as solving for $u$. You need to put $(A-\lambda I)$ and $k_1$ in a matrix, then do Gaussian elimination.

Comment: \begin{bmatrix}
    {-1}       & {-1} & {1} & {1} \\
    {3}       & {0} & {-3} & {0} \\
    {2}       & {-1} & {-2} & {1}
\end{bmatrix}

Comment: So we have to make the first 3x3 to be the I but when you start doing that gaussian thing, you seee that it's impossible

Comment: @Harton: No you don't make it $I$. $A-\lambda I$ is never invertible, so doing Gaussian elimination will give you infinitely many solutions. If you solve it, you will get $x_2=-1$, $x_1=x_3$. Picking one as $k_2$: $(1,-1,1)$ would work.

Comment: You are right about the system but then again the coneficients are not accurate. i get that a=3/7;b=-7/8;c=7

Comment: @Harton: After you solve a system, you can always plug them back to double check.